# How to show, not download, images in apache?

Tags: html, apache, image

I'm dynamically generating some charts using mod_python, in .png and .pdf formats. When a user points to /some/path/some_imagefile_name.png, I want to show the image within the browser, like in [this url](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/cemetery.png). I also want the image to be accessible from an HTML `<img src=>` tag.

So far, whenever I point my browser to a .png address from my server, the .png and .pdf are automatically downloaded instead of being viewed. How should I fix this?

I tagged this under Apache, since I figured it would be an Apache config thing. If it's not, please point me towards the right direction.

Edit: Whoops, never mind... First, the correct MIME type for .png is `image/png` not `img/png`, and second, Chrome automatically downloads all .pdfs.

Comment: what content-type headers does the server send?

Comment: For urls ending in .png, it sends image/png, and for .pdf it sends application/pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your python app is adding a `Content-Disposition; attachment` header when it should not.